# Indy SMTP Connect handled differently on different PCs

Tags: delphi, smtp, delphi-7, indy10

In a Delphi Sports Club membership program, I send bulk emails to the members using the club's BTConnect account, which has been migrated to Office365. Recently, BT upped the authentication and I changed the SMTP parameters from satNone to satDefault and utUseExplicitTLS. If I run the program from home, it works as expected:

```
Stat Connected.
Recv 20/11/2012 16:36:02: 220 pod51016.outlook.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Tue, 20 Nov 2012 16:36:01 +0000<EOL>
Sent 20/11/2012 16:36:02: EHLO macxp<EOL>
Recv 20/11/2012 16:36:02: 250-pod51016.outlook.com Hello [81.155.5.61]<EOL>250-SIZE 36700160<EOL>250-PIPELINING<EOL>250-DSN<EOL>250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES<EOL>250-STARTTLS<EOL>250-AUTH<EOL>250-8BITMIME<EOL>250-BINARYMIME<EOL>250 CHUNKING<EOL>
Sent 20/11/2012 16:36:02: STARTTLS<EOL>
Recv 20/11/2012 16:36:02: 220 2.0.0 SMTP server ready<EOL>
Sent 20/11/2012 16:36:02: EHLO macxp<EOL>
Recv 20/11/2012 16:36:02: 250-pod51016.outlook.com Hello [81.155.5.61]<EOL>250-SIZE 36700160<EOL>250-PIPELINING<EOL>250-DSN<EOL>250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES<EOL>250-AUTH LOGIN<EOL>250-8BITMIME<EOL>250-BINARYMIME<EOL>250 CHUNKING<EOL>
Sent 20/11/2012 16:36:02: AUTH LOGIN<EOL>
Recv 20/11/2012 16:36:02: 334 deleted<EOL>
Sent 20/11/2012 16:36:02: deleted<EOL>
Recv 20/11/2012 16:36:02: 334 deleted<EOL>
Sent 20/11/2012 16:36:02: deleted<EOL>
Recv 20/11/2012 16:36:04: 235 2.7.0 Authentication successful<EOL>
Sent 20/11/2012 16:36:04: RSET<EOL>
Recv 20/11/2012 16:36:10: 250 2.0.0 Resetting<EOL>
Sent 20/11/2012 16:36:10: MAIL FROM: <deleted@btconnect.com><EOL>
Recv 20/11/2012 16:36:10: 250 2.1.0 Sender OK<EOL>
```

and off it goes, no problem. 
If I take the program to the sports club and run it there, I get this:

```
Stat Connected.
Recv 12/11/2012 15:17:31: 220 pod51014.outlook.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Mon, 12 Nov 2012 15:17:03 +0000<EOL>
Sent 12/11/2012 15:17:31: EHLO ovscbob<EOL>
Recv 12/11/2012 15:17:31: 250-pod51014.outlook.com Hello [81.149.229.105]<EOL>250-SIZE 36700160<EOL>250-PIPELINING<EOL>250-DSN<EOL>250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES<EOL>250-STARTTLS<EOL>250-AUTH<EOL>250-8BITMIME<EOL>250-BINARYMIME<EOL>250 CHUNKING<EOL>
Sent 12/11/2012 15:17:31: STARTTLS<EOL>
Recv 12/11/2012 15:17:31: 220 2.0.0 SMTP server ready<EOL>
Sent 12/11/2012 15:17:31: QUIT<EOL>
Stat Disconnected.
```

It appears that Indy is issuing QUIT instead of the second EHLO command, but I can't find out why. I changed the setup to use satSASL and the related mechanisms, with the same result. It works fine at home, but not from the club. Is there any way I can resolve this? I updated Indy to the most recent version about a week ago as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the server receives a `STARTTLS` command and replies back with a success response, it expects `TIdSMTP` to initiate an SSL/TLS handshake before sending any further commands.  In this case, the SSL/TLS handshake has to be failing, and you should be getting an exception raised.  `TIdSMTPBase.StartTLS()` calls `Disconnect()` if an exception occurs.  That is the only way `TIdSMTP` would send a `QUIT` command after a successful `STARTTLS` command, instead of sending a second `EHLO`.

Comment: Thank you Remy.It occurs to me that I have not updated the SSL package on the club machine when I switched to the latest Indy 10 download.